# JS click event depending on div width

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, click

I am trying to resize two divs with a click event in combination with an if query. If the div **`#slide_3_1`** is `100%` and **`#arrow_right_3`** is clicked, than the div **`#slide_3_1`** should be `0px` wide and div **`#slide_3_2`** should be `100%` wide.

When i click **`#arrow_right_3`** nothing happens. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
var $div_width = $('#slide_3_1').attr('width');

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#arrow_right_3").click(function(){
        if ($div_width > 0) {
            $("#slide_3_1").css('width', '0px');
            $("#slide_3_2").css('width', '100%');
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="section_3" class="section">
    <div class="arrow_left" id="arrow_left_3">Arrow left</div>
    <div class="arrow_right" id="arrow_right_3">Arrow right</div>
    <div id="slide_3_1" class="slide"></div>
    <div id="slide_3_2" class="slide"></div>
    <div id="slide_3_3" class="slide"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I assume `d$iv_width` is a typo? (first line). If not, that's your problem.

Comment: Can you stick a breakpoint inside your `click` handler and see if the event handler is even getting called?

Comment: I checked the typo. When it comes to the breakpoint, it doesn't get called

Comment: If your function isn't getting called, then there is something wrong with how you are binding it. Can you show your html?

Comment: <div id="section_3" class="section">
  <div class="arrow_left" id="arrow_left_3">Arrow left</div>
  <div class="arrow_right" id="arrow_right_3">Arrow right</div>
  <div id="slide_3_1" class="slide"> </div>
  <div id="slide_3_2" class="slide"> </div>
  <div id="slide_3_3" class="slide"> </div>
</div>

Comment: Your binding works [fine](http://jsfiddle.net/N994Z/). Of course, as @Jerodev suggested, you do have a problem with using `attr("width")` because it will return `undefined` as you have it. Also, you should move the variable declaration for `$div_width` to inside your doc ready function so you can be sure that the div you are trying to access actually exists at the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your code, on the first line it should be ´$div_width´.

Also, you should get the width by using ´$div.width()´. This will always return the width even if the element doesn't has a width attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Putting together everything in the comments, here's a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/N994Z/1/

```
$(function() {
    var $div_width = $('#slide_3_1').width();
    $("#arrow_right_3").click(function () {
        if ($div_width > 0) {
            $("#slide_3_1").css('width', '0px');
            $("#slide_3_2").css('width', '100%');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question it appears you have two divs with the id "slide_3_1"

"If the **div #slide_3_1 is** 100% and #arrow_right_3 is clicked, than **another div #slide_3_1** should be 0px wide"

Comment: I'm sorry for my english, of course there is only one div #slide_3_1 ;)

Comment: in that case I would go with Jerodev's answer